# In the browser inactive tab, javascript alert is sometimes ignored and the page is moved

Tags: javascript, alert, browser-tab

I implemented the logout function in JS if 5 minutes have passed by checking every 1 second as shown below.

```
// logout
let restAutologoutTime = (60 * 5); // 5minute
autoLogout = setInterval(function() {
    --restAutologoutTime;
    if(restAutologoutTime <= 0) {
        // clear 
        clearInterval(autoLogout);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('logout');
            location.href = 'somethingUrl';
        }, 1000)
    }
}, 1000);
```

If the tab is active, an alert is executed and the location only occurs when 'OK' is pressed. (chrome, edge browser)
However, if the tab was not active (turn on another tab and search), sometimes the location was executed without alert.
It knows that browsers reduce resources on inactive tabs.

Is there a way to make the location move after the alert window is exposed, regardless of tab activation or deactivation?

Comment: don't use alert, show a modal for example and have your code written in such a way that does what you want when the modal is interacted with

Comment: @JaromandaX 
Thanks for the advice.
I wanted to notify the user with an alert.
Currently, all information on the homepage uses alert, so I wanted to use alert for logout as well for uniformity.